# jquery onclick fires twice as many to previous click

Tags: jquery, events

The following onclick fires exactly double times than previous click. in other words when I click it first time it works as intended and fires only once. but when I click again (on the same row or the other) it fires twice. if I click for the third time it fires 8 times then 16 times then 32 times. whats going on?

```
calcTotals: function (table){
        var totals=[];
        $(table).find('tbody').children('tr').each(function(r,row){

            $(row).on('click',function(e){
                $(this).toggleClass('selectedForTotal');
                $(table).find('tbody').children('tr:last').remove();
                dialog.calcTotals(table);
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            })

             if($(row).hasClass('selectedForTotal')){
                $(this).children('td').each(function(c,cell){
                    if($(cell).hasClass('realNumber')){

                        cell.style.textAlign='right';
                        cell=$(cell).html().replace(/,/g,'').replace('(','-').replace(')','');
                        if (!totals[c]) totals[c]=0;
                        totals[c]+=parseFloat(cell);
                        $(cell).val(formatNumber(cell,2,false,true,true));

                    }else {cell.style.textAlign='left';}
                })
            }
        })

        var newRow=$('<tr>').appendTo($(table).find('tbody'))
            .attr({'id':'totals','class':'highlightRow','tabIndex':'1'})
            .on('click',function(i,item){
                $(this).toggleClass('highlightRow');
        }).css('cursor','pointer');

        console.log('total : '+totals);

        $(totals).each(function(i,item){
            $('<td>').html(item?   formatNumber(totals[i],2,false,true,true):'').appendTo(newRow);
        })

        $(newRow).focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `calcTotals` function binds the `click` event handlers, but then your `click` event handlers call `calcTotals` (which binds another `click` event handler to all of those elements).

So you call `calcTotals` once, and you have one `click` event handler per element. You click on one of those, `calcTotals` gets called again, and you now have two `click` event handlers per element. Then you click again, both event handlers get fired, binding another two `click` event handlers (now have a total of four). Next click adds another four (for a total of eight), etc.

You need to bind the `click` event handler a single time, separate from the `calcTotals` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding event **repeatedly** in `each()` that is the reason for event is triggered repeatedly, Assign some class to row on which you want to bind the event and use class selector to bind event.

```
 $(".rowclass").on('click',function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('selectedForTotal');
        $(table).find('tbody').children('tr:last').remove();
        dialog.calcTotals(table);
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop the default action, and then register a new one.

This will cause all previous clicks bound to element not to execute....

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the previous handler with off() before attaching a new element with on() 
I hope this code may help you..!!! 
$('body').off('click', '.collapsible').on("click", ".collapsible", function (e) {
   /* Do somthing */
});